# What is the SQL Server connection string in c# application for client computers

Tags: string, authentication, connection, database-connection

I am unable to access database using c# application from all client computers in the same network but main computer sql server worked fine. Note: all settings like TCP/IP ping, firewall, .net installed is set already. Is there any good code to establish connection or connection string?

Code to establish connection or connection string accessible through other computer without sql server installation